# How to load the Data into the Kendo tree from the database in MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am using the Kendo Tree in my MVC Application. 
I want to know how we can load the data into the KendoTree from the DataBase.

Comment: Are you referring to the [Kendo UI TreeView](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/treeview/remote-data.html)?

Comment: Yes, I am referring that in the page.I did the adding the node and child node part of it and also the saving. But when I come to edit the tree , I am able to get the Json data in Controller but, from there i don't know how to get the added tree back.

Comment: Could you add the code you are having trouble with to your question